# How to loop java code

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

How do i loop this code until the user presses N. I want a prompt after its first done that says " Continue? [Y/N]" No matter if its uppercase or not.I think i know how to do it but im not sure how to incorporate the firstLetters.equals

```
package firstLast;

import java.util.Scanner;// Imported Scanner class 

public class firstLast {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Miwand's First Last program
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in); // Insert Scanner to get input from user later on
        String word; // The initial word

        System.out.println("Please enter a string longer than 4 letters"); // Asking user to enter string that's more than 4 chars long

        word = in.nextLine(); // Getting input from user

        for ()
            String firstLetters = (word.substring(0, 2)); // Getting the first two letters

            String lastLetters = (word.substring(word.length() - 2)); // Getting the last two letters

            if (firstLetters.equalsIgnoreCase(lastLetters)) // Ignores case and checks if the firstLetters and lastLetters are the same
            {
                System.out.println("The fist two letters and the last two are the same!"); // If they are than print out this
            }
            else 
            {
                System.out.println("Different :("); // If they are different, print out this
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sigh. You are expecting other people to spend their time to help you do your homework. But you dont find the 3 minutes it takes to properly format/indent all of your question.

Comment: And hint: all those // trailing comments ... few of them are of any real use. Dont train yourself to put down such line noise. Dont comment **what** code is doing; only comment the **why** - when that isn't obvious from reading the code itself.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's easy to find examples of Java loops. Maybe check Stack Overflow documentation.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (true) {
    < body of the loop >
    System.out.println("Continue? [Y/N]");
    String ans = in.nextLine();
    if (ans.toLowerCase().equals("n"))
        break;
    //check if y, or just loop anyway
}
```

The code for an endless `for` loop is `for(;;)` , anyway

Edit: fixed "True" into "true"

Comment: Its underling the True part in the while loop how do i fix that

Comment: just make it lower case instead @MiwandBakhtari like so `while(true)`

Comment: Yea i got that part but now the problem is that it displays the first letter is the same continuously. I put the while loop right before the first if statement

Comment: can confirm, in java booleans are lowercase. my bad

Comment: yes @MiwandBakhtari but it still not correct it should look like `while(true){/*Your code here (inside)*/} // not here outside the loop`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this like below, but you only have to consider one condition. Either Y or N. You can modify this as your requirement.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (sc.nextLine().equals("Y")){
   // Do Stuff
}
```